# Using positive lookbehind in Movable Type templates causes error due to < in pattern string

Tags: regex, types, lookbehind, movable

I'm attempting to limit the length of a displayed string to the first 50 characters plus any needed to end at the next word boundary. I'm using the regex_replace filter in the template tag to replace all the characters after the pattern match with "...". However, using the positive lookbehind requires the less-than symbol which apparently MT is interpreting as the start of a tag. This is causing nearby tags to break and the template fails to publish, reporting an error. It there any way to incorporate the positive lookbehind into the template?

```
<mt:Ignore>Limit entryTitle length by discarding any/all chars after whole word containing 50th char</mt:Ignore>
<mt:entryTitle regex_replace="/((?<=.{50}\b).+)/i","...">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an XML problem: The "<" character is illegal within a tag. Encode it as `&lt;`:

```
<mt:entryTitle regex_replace="/((?&lt;=.{50}\b).+)/i","...">
```

Comment: I was going to suggest the exact same thing, but there's one thing I'm not certain about. From my understanding `<` and `&` are both illegal characters in XML tags. Does `&lt;` need to be escaped as `\&lt;` because of `&`?

Comment: @l'L'l it doesn't need escaping, because the character sequence `&lt;` is a special XML entity (treated as a single "thing"). You can test it yourself [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp)